# How do i get the max 2 column names by values sorting row wise in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like:

| A_ZZ_CR | B_YY_CR | C_WW_CR | D_XX_CR | E_VV_CR | F_OO_CR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.51 | 0.12 | 0.69 | 0.72 | 0.04 | 0.78 |
| 0.65 | 0.53 | 0.18 | 0.68 | 0.70 | 0.08 |
| 0.63 | 0.45 | 0.20 | 0.73 | 0.72 | -0.02 |
| 0.59 | 0.41 | 0.17 | 0.72 | 0.69 | 0.10 |
| 0.66 | 0.43 | 0.23 | 0.74 | 0.71 | 0.16 |

Output i want is max of columns per row.

| A_ZZ_CR | B_YY_CR | C_WW_CR | D_XX_CR | E_VV_CR | F_OO_CR | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.51 | 0.12 | 0.69 | 0.72 | 0.04 | 0.78 | OO, XX |
| 0.65 | 0.53 | 0.18 | 0.68 | 0.70 | 0.08 | VV, XX |
| 0.63 | 0.45 | 0.20 | 0.73 | 0.72 | -0.02 | XX, VV |
| 0.59 | 0.41 | 0.17 | 0.72 | 0.69 | 0.10 | XX, VV |
| 0.66 | 0.43 | 0.23 | 0.74 | 0.71 | 0.16 | XX, VV |

I got this code but it gives max column name not max of 2 or 3.

```
# look for the max values in each row
mxs = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
df['OUTPUT'] = (df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
                  .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.nlargest(2).index), axis=1)
               )
```

Or with `groupby.apply`:

```
df['OUTPUT'] = (
     df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[1]).stack()
       .groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
       .apply(lambda g: ', '.join(g.nlargest(2).droplevel(0).index))
    )
```

Output:

```
   A_ZZ_CR  B_YY_CR  C_WW_CR  D_XX_CR  E_VV_CR  F_OO_CR  OUTPUT
0     0.51     0.12     0.69     0.72     0.04     0.78  OO, XX
1     0.65     0.53     0.18     0.68     0.70     0.08  VV, XX
2     0.63     0.45     0.20     0.73     0.72    -0.02  XX, VV
3     0.59     0.41     0.17     0.72     0.69     0.10  XX, VV
4     0.66     0.43     0.23     0.74     0.71     0.16  XX, VV
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `argsort` to get the sorted indices then broadcast the column names and select the cols corresponding to max two values

```
i = np.argsort(df, axis=1)
c = df.columns.str.split('_').str[1]
df['output'] = list(c.values[i][:, -2:])
```

Result

```
   A_ZZ_CR  B_YY_CR  C_WW_CR  D_XX_CR  E_VV_CR  F_OO_CR    output
0     0.51     0.12     0.69     0.72     0.04     0.78  [XX, OO]
1     0.65     0.53     0.18     0.68     0.70     0.08  [XX, VV]
2     0.63     0.45     0.20     0.73     0.72    -0.02  [VV, XX]
3     0.59     0.41     0.17     0.72     0.69     0.10  [VV, XX]
4     0.66     0.43     0.23     0.74     0.71     0.16  [VV, XX]
```

Comment: How to also get the values?